# Power BI Analyze in Excel - Can't select "Value"

Tags: powerbi, export-to-excel, powerpivot

I am trying to connect the dataset in Power BI Service through Excel. However, when I try to drag and drop the "Value" field into  "Values" field under "PivotTable Fields", it don't allow me to do it. Anyone know how to solve it? I have checked in the community fabic web but there's no clear answer as the field I'm selecting is a measure but its not recognising it as one. Thank you

[Excel error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvDeE.png)